# VB.Net Coder Menu Not Showing

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net 2015 edition and it's coder menu not showing. How to add that?

Image Of Menu in Coder:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Options from the main menu. Text Editor > Basic > General and check the 'Navigation bar' box.  ALWAYS look in the IDE options when you want to manipulate the IDE.  Yes, there's a lot in there, but that's why you should have a look through it BEFORE you need to use it: so that you have a fair idea of what's available.  Anything related to the code editor window specifically is under the Text Editor section.